# Custom PDF size

Tags: jxbrowser

I have a webpage that is 3000px wide and sometimes 3000px tall. When I save it as a PDF, it formats the pdf as 8.5 x 11 and all of my webpage is missing. Is there a way that I can make the pdf 3000px x 3000px and allow my clients to scale the pdf to what ever paper size they have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now JxBrowser allows saving web page as PDF document with A4 paper size only. Functionality that allows customizing paper size when saving web page as PDF will be added in one of the next versions.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Is there a way that I can save the page as a custom sized PNG in the meantime?